# #down_votes methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've created the specs to check the up and down votes but when tested the complete file it fails on the last method (down_votes), but when checking one by one it all pass. I'm using a before method to instantiate the @user, @post, signing in the user and setting up the request environment.

Here's below my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe VotesController do 

 include TestFactories
 include Devise::TestHelpers

 before do
    request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
    @user = authenticated_user
    @post = associated_post
    sign_in @user
 end

 describe '#up_vote' do
   it "adds an up-vote to the post" do

     expect {
       post( :up_vote, post_id: @post.id )
     }.to change{ @post.up_votes }.by 1
   end
 end

 describe '#down_vote' do
   it "adds an down-vote to the post" do

     expect {
       post( :down_vote, post_id: @post.id )
     }.to change{ @post.down_votes }.by -1
   end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
}.to change{ @post.down_votes }.by -1
```

Try amending that line to use a positive integer:

```
}.to change{ @post.down_votes }.by 1
```

(assuming the `down_votes` method is supposed to be a total count of all down votes).

Comment: OK... got it. I was caught thinking on passing the negative value.